# Cannot convert to utf-8 in python 3

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I am trying to read a file which has data like this

```
AntÃƒÂ³nio FÃƒÂ©lix da Costa...JÃƒÂ©rÃƒÂ´me d'Ambrosio
```

Here is the code..

```
df = pd.read_csv('formula_e_race_results.csv', usecols = ["driver"],encoding = "utf-8")
```

the results is not coming properly...

```
AntÃƒÂ³nio FÃƒÂ©lix da Costa
```

i need to get the english name

Comment: You may try to share the original file. Because I cannot understand the problem without trying the exact code

Comment: What is your expected output and what do you get?

Comment: From your question, it doesn't looks like a UTF-8 encoded string. Also your question is not clear.

Comment: Try with another encoding instead. Probably try a few of the common non-UTF-8 ones.

Comment: That string appears to be ISO-8859-15 (or one of the other ISO-8859 variants) that has been incorrectly encoded as UTF-8. In other words, the string has been mangled by improper encoding. Is that really the content of the CSV file? Is your locale a UTF-8 locale? Amend your question to show the output of `head -1 formula_e_race_results.csv | od -tx1z`. Obviously if the first line doesn't contain non-ASCII characters modify that command to select a line that does have non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @sdeb: If you figured out what was wrong you should share that as an answer. If you've simply abandoned this question you should delete it so that people aren't left wondering if you still need help.